# Observer const-correctness

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to implement observer pattern into my project.

Imagine simple a class method

```
const Buffer * data() const
{
    if (m_data)
        return m_data;

    // read some data from input
    m_data = fstream.read(1000);

    // subscribe to our buffer
    m_data->Subscribe(this);

    return m_data;
}
```

This method is used to read input data, but the operation could be time consuming, it is therefore delayed.

Class Buffer is simple wrapper above std::vector, which notifies observers, when it's data being altered.

The containing class needs to be notified, when Buffer data changes.
However, since this method is marked as const, I am unable to subscribe to the Buffer.

I was able to figure out 3 solutions:

**1.** Cast away const-ness

```
    // subscribe to our buffer
    m_data->Subscribe(const_cast<Object*>(this));
```

I am not sure, whether this is correct, but it works.

**2.** Change const-ness of notification method and observers

```
    vector<const IModifyObserver*> m_observers;
    void Subscribe(const IModifyObserver* observer);
    void Unsubscribe(const IModifyObserver* observer)
    virtual void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable*) const override
    {
        m_dirty = true;
    }
```

This one has a downfall, if I need to change properties they all have to be mutable and all functions I call must be const, which also does not make any sense.

**3.** Remove const from everywhere

```
    Buffer * data();
    bool Equals(Object& other);
    Buffer* m_data;
```

This would most probably mean, that I would have to remove const from whole solution, since I can't event call Equals for two different const objects.

**How to properly solve this problem?**

Full Code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class IModifyObservable;

// class for receiving changed notifications
class IModifyObserver
{
public:
    virtual void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable* observee) = 0;
    virtual ~IModifyObserver() = 0;
};

// class for producing changed notifications
class IModifyObservable
{
public:
    // Add new subscriber to notify
    void Subscribe(IModifyObserver* observer)
    {
        m_observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    // Remove existing subscriber
    void Unsubscribe(IModifyObserver* observer)
    {
        for (auto it = m_observers.begin(); it != m_observers.end(); ++it) {
            if (observer == *it) {
                m_observers.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Notify all subscribers
    virtual void OnChanged()
    {
        auto size = m_observers.size();
        for (decltype(size) i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            m_observers[i]->ObserveeChanged(this);
        }
    }

    virtual ~IModifyObservable() = 0;

private:
    vector<IModifyObserver*> m_observers;
};

IModifyObserver::~IModifyObserver() {}
IModifyObservable::~IModifyObservable() {}

// Example class implementing IModifyObservable
class Buffer : public IModifyObservable
{
private:
    vector<char> m_data;
};

// Example class implementing IModifyObserver
class Object : public IModifyObserver
{
public:

    // Both share implementation
    //Buffer * data();
    const Buffer * data() const
    {
        // Just read some data
        //m_data = fstream.read(1000);

        // Subscribe to our buffer
        m_data->Subscribe(this);

        return m_data;
    }

    virtual void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable*) override
    {
        m_dirty = true;
    }

    // This is just for example, why do I need const data method
    bool Equals(const Object& other) const { return data() == other.data();
}

private:
    mutable Buffer* m_data = new Buffer();
    bool m_dirty;
};

int main()
{
    Object obj1;
    Object obj2;
    auto data1 = obj1.data();
    auto data2 = obj2.data();
    bool equals = (obj1.Equals(obj2));
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in const-ness, so I'm not posting an answer, but I'd do option 1: Ensure that your `ObserveeChanged()` does not actually modify `this` and then cast away the `const` to fulfull the interface.

Comment: `m_data->Subscribe(this);` should not be done in a getter. In addition, `m_data = fstream.read(1000);` already broke the `const` part.

Comment: m_data is marked as mutable. This is common practice in every cache method. Where should "m_data->Subscribe(this);" be called?

Comment: If there is a need to modify internal state in a const method, inevitably this means that your interface to the outside world is broken (i.e. where necessary, some uses don't have access to a non-const version when they actually require it.) Casting const away is a horrible hack IMHO and one that should be avoided. If you follow the simple rule of modify only in non-const methods, your compiler will tell you where in the code there is a mis-use, and it should be simply fixing those (either make do with const observers or give a non-const instance..)

Comment: @Nim I don't really understand. If I modify mutable property in const method everything works. This is not broken. As I mentioned, removing const would mean, that even Equals method cannot be const, that I am unable to compare const objects

Comment: @Gotcha - see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gets in the way here is you deferred reading. Without this optimisation the right way would be to separate constant and non-constant methods:

```
const Buffer * data() const
{
    return m_data;
}

void InitializeData()
{
    // Just read some data
    m_data = fstream.read(1000);

    // Subscribe to our buffer
    m_data->Subscribe(this);
}
```

Then optimize it the way you want:

```
const Buffer * data() const
{
    if(m_data == nullptr)
        const_cast<Object*>(this)->InitializeData();

    return m_data;
}
```

And you don't need `m_data` to mutable anymore.

---

BTW. To make this deferred initialization work you should initialize `m_data` member with `nullptr`. Otherwise this object will be created while constructing and your `if(m_data)` will be always true.

---

UPD

So here is another solution to your problem

```
class Object : public IModifyObserver
{
public:

    Object()
    : m_data(nullptr)
    , m_dataInitialized(false)
    // ...
    {
        m_data = new Buffer(); // << Create buffer here
        m_data->Subscribe(this); // << And subscribe right away
    }

    const Buffer * data() const
    {
        if(!m_dataInitialized) // << Initialize if needed
        {
            // Set data here
            m_data->setData(fstream.read(1000)); // << Probably you want to suppress notifications here
            m_dataInitialized = true;
        }
        return m_data;
    }
    // ...
private:
    mutable Buffer* m_data;
    mutable bool m_dataInitialized; // << Added another flag to see if data was initialized
    // ...
};
```

Comment: This solution looks almost like number 1. on the list. However `const_cast<Object*>(this)` seems really dirty to me. I also believe, that the behavior is undefined, if you try to cast away const-ness of a constant object and then modify it.

Comment: @Gotcha `const_cast` is safe when the object being casted was originally non-const. So you belief in undefined behaviour depends on how you use this code. To avoid this cast you can manually call `InitializeData()` when `data()` return `nullptr`.

Comment: I would like to solve this, without having any assumptions about the caller, if you understand. Solution to call initialize when data returns null method is working, but I don't like it either.

Comment: @Gotcha I've added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of refactoring your code, I couldn't see where the initial call to `data()` would happen in your example, but I imagine it is called in a 2-phase way (construct -> then call method). Sticking with the simple rule..

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class IModifyObservable;

// class for receiving changed notifications
class IModifyObserver
{
public:
    virtual void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable* observee) = 0;
    virtual ~IModifyObserver() = default;
};

// class for producing changed notifications
class IModifyObservable
{
public:
    // This method modifies state - so non-const
    void Subscribe(IModifyObserver* observer)
    {
        observers_.push_back(observer);
    }

    // This method modifies state - so non-const
    void Unsubscribe(IModifyObserver* observer)
    {
        observers_.erase(find(begin(observers_), end(observers_), observer));
    }

    // Again as the internal state of the observer is modified, this is non-const
    virtual void OnChanged()
    {
        for (auto observer : observers_) {
            observer->ObserveeChanged(this);
        }
    }

    virtual ~IModifyObservable() = default;

private:
    vector<IModifyObserver*> observers_;
};

// Example class implementing IModifyObservable
class Buffer : public IModifyObservable
{
    vector<char> data_;
};

// Example class implementing IModifyObserver
class Object : public IModifyObserver
{
public:

    // The first call to the non-cost version triggers the lazy load...
    const Buffer* data()
    {
        if (!data_) {
            data_ = make_unique<Buffer>();
            // Now start the read operation
            // :
            // Subscribe, I imagine you only want to do this once?
            data_->Subscribe(this);
        }
        return data_.get();
    }

    // Calls to const version returns what's there...
    const Buffer* data() const
    {        
        return data_.get();
    }

    // This has to be non-cost as the internal state is being modified
    void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable*) override
    {
        dirty_ = true;
    }

    // Operator uses const versions, which will use const methods
    friend
    bool operator==(const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs) {
        if (lhs.data() && rhs.data()) {
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    unique_ptr<Buffer> data_;
    bool dirty_ = false;
};

int main()
{
    Object obj1;
    Object obj2;
    auto data1 = obj1.data();
    auto data2 = obj2.data();
    bool equals = obj1 == obj2;
}
```

There are no hacks, it should just work...

Comment: The whole question is about the `const Buffer* data() const` method, which you changed, that it no longer reads input data. This would mean, that I have to call non-const method to initialize data somewhere before, but this is what I am trying to avoid. This whole class is basically about lazy-loading the buffer data

Comment: There-in lies the problem, if you expect the object's internals to be lazy loaded, you should propagate a non-const instance. Else eager load and propagate a const instance. Mixing semantics is only going to land you in trouble later... You'll end up having const functions and mutable members... frankly horrible...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to register in the a getter, register in initialization:

```
class Object : public IModifyObserver
{
public:
    Object() { m_data.Subscribe(this); }

    const Buffer* data() const { return m_data; }
    Buffer* data() { return m_data; }

    void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable*) override { m_dirty = true; }
private:
    Buffer m_data;
    bool m_dirty = false;
};
```

With lazy initialization, it becomes:

```
class Object : public IModifyObserver
{
public:
    Object() { m_data.Subscribe(this); }

    Buffer& data()
    {
        if (!m_data.is_initialized()) { m_data.initialize(); }
        return m_data;
    }
    const Buffer& data() const
    {
        if (!m_data.is_initialized()) { m_data.initialize(); }
        return m_data;
    }

    void ObserveeChanged(IModifyObservable*) override { m_dirty = true; }

private:
    mutable Buffer m_data;
    bool m_dirty = false;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54205475efee3e9a)